# Error: Cannot find module 'wrappy'

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

When I try to restore my packages via yarn I'm receiving the following error:

```
npm run yarn --ignore-platform --ignore-optional

...

error C:\Users\mdepouw\source\repos\MyRepo\node_modules\node-sass: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node scripts/install.js
Arguments:
Directory: C:\Users\mdepouw\source\repos\MyRepo\node_modules\node-sass
Output:
module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'wrappy'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\mdepouw\source\repos\MyRepo\node_modules\inflight\inflight.js:1:76)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
```

When I a `npm install` it works fine.

Why does one work but not the other?

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when you update npm. To resolve this go to path "C:\Users[username]\AppData\Roaming" and delete "npm" and "npm-cache" folders. Then uninstall nodejs and reinstall using updated installer. This should solve your problem.